# Include function into main file problem (CodeBlocks)

Tags: c, include, codeblocks, precompiled-headers

I'm having a conundrum with CodeBlocks in sharing code among different files using headers (.h) and source code (.c).

I have three files: `main.c`, `anotherSourceFile.c`, `sampleHeader.h`

Long story short, when I'm trying to include a function in the `main.c` file - e.g. calling a sample `foo()` function inside the  `main()` function - I get an `undefined reference to 'foo'` error.

This is the code inside each file:

Inside the `main.c` file

```
// Include the header
#include "sampleHeader.h"

// Include standard libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    // Call to the would-be imported function
    foo();    // WHERE THE ERROR OCCUR: undefined reference to 'foo'

    return 0;
}
```

Inside the `sampleHeader.h` file...

```
#ifndef SAMPLEHEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define SAMPLEHEADER_H_INCLUDED

// foo() function prototype
void foo(void);

#endif // SAMPLEHEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Inside the `anotherSourceCode.c` file...

```
// Include the header
#include "sampleHeader.h"

// Include standard libraries
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// foo() function implementation
void foo() {
    printf("Hello from foo.");
}
```

I don't get where is the kink and how to work it out, neither do I know where to look in order to find a solution. How can I get rid of the `undefined reference to 'foo'` error?

Comment: ```ifndef SAMPLEHEADER_H``` should fixed you error. Remember to do this too ```define SAMPLEHEADER_H```

Comment: It's not about your source code.  It's about how you are building the program.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Most likely the linker is complaining because you aren't telling it to link anotherSourceCode,o.